# Google Maps API: Show marker on map using GPS latitude longitude coordinators

Tags: javascript, ruby, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I have different locations to show on separate maps. Here are some examples of latitudes and longitudes I have:

"latitude" : "49 29.219N", "longitude" : "000 11.042E"

"latitude" : "49 27.264N","longitude" : "000 10.305E"

"latitude" : "49 28.456N", "longitude" : "000 09.977E"

As it seems that this format is unacceptable for Google Maps API, how can I change them to an acceptable format to mark on the map using Javascript or Ruby?

Comment: Does Google Maps API have anything to manage it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map longitude and latitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705678/google-map-longitude-and-latitude)

Comment: related question: [how to convert between degrees, minutes, seconds to Decimal coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263959/how-to-convert-between-degrees-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-coordinates)

Comment: Duplicate, answered here: Converting latitude and longitude to decimal values
 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140189/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-decimal-values)

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for your help buy the format I have is a little bit different. I will post the solution later for the others.

Comment: @ronenmiller Thanks, the same as my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me in an old version of Google Maps API

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(hotspot.lat,hotspot.long);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: TAWI.map,
        title: hotspot.name,
        icon: TAWI.pin.normal
});
```

being:

- *hotspot.lat* the lattitude of the marker in decimal format,
- *hotspot.long* the longitude of the marker in decimal format,
- *hotspot.name* the name of the marker,
- *TAWI.pin.normal* a custom icon to show and
- *TAWI.map* the Google Maps rendered on the page

You should check the current documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

And this would help converting from one notation to the other 
https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Convert_degree